# Restrictions in apache

Tags: apache, apache2

I need to configure access to some different method, and to add more different users (admin, user1 ....)

```
<Location /webdav>
    DAV On
    #Require valid-user
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/webdav.password
    Require user admin
    OPTIONS none
    <LimitExcept PUT DELETE GET>
        Require user admin
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I cant use Require valid-user , because not all users need to have same access

Comment: Google "apache require group".

Comment: @GuntramBlohm , and what to do in case if users are in different groups ?

Comment: Users can be in more than one group. Create a group "webdav_allow", put all users that should have access into that group *in addition to* the groups they're in, then require group webdav_allow in your configuration.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm , so in case if we have 10 users and 20 different cases of rules, we will need 20 groups?
May be are some more optimal variant?

Comment: If you really have 20 cases of rules, that have nothing to do with each other, you need 20 groups, yes. There's no other way to model a "User X may use URL Y" relation. But, most real life situations aren't that complex -- normally you can get away with groups like "administrator, moderator, editor, reader", and give several groups access to your directory at once (check <RequireAny> to learn how).